# How do I get an Asound-cm106 (USB) sound card to work?

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a USB sound device asound-cm106 which apparently has the cm6206 chipset.

I want to use it because I give the hell up trying to get my built in soundcard to work with my current setup (it was always fine before) I can `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` to get the refusing-to-do-anything built in card to appear in the sound card list but I have been left feeling like a useless idiot trying to figure out my way around this unity thing to try and make the USB device show up short of virgin sacrifice and prayers to dark gods. Clearly sound is a lot more complicated than, say, running my companies Apache servers and coding OO-PHP.

The forums have been unusually unhelpful with every thread having wildly different answers which all seem to consist of downloading stuff, writing epics scripts in sub-voodoo languages, replacing the entire sound stack, patching the kernel or otherwise doing stuff that is so far over my head as to be incomprehensible.

Threads I've found:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/535476
- http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1208429.html
- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-uk/2009-June/019046.html

All I want is to plug the silly thing in and get sound out of my speakers. Could someone offer me a solution that any fool could follow. You may collect my geek card on your way through.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit) with an AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 555 Processor.

Comment: Every on-board HDA device is wired differently, so you need a new kernel for new hardware; 12.04 is quite outdated by now. On a properly configured system, disabling the on-board device and just plugging the USB device in should work.

Comment: Please add the links to the forum posts you've checked out to your question, it might provide clues for the answerers!

Comment: Could you try to run 13.04 from a Live CD and see if it works? Hardware support may only appear in newer Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Is your sound card recognized in ubuntu as an audio device?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `alsamixer`.

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type following:

   $ alsamixer
2. Then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to Select your sound card, and change settings for it
   (increase/decrease volume, mute/unmute).

   [image: alsamixer]
3. After you have made the changes, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit.
4. To save `alsamixer` changes for reboots:

   $ sudo alsactl store

**Links:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer
- http://alsa.opensrc.org/Alsamixer

Comment: Alsamixer correctly detects the extra channels, but this doesn't help with sound from the desktop. Even `speaker-test` still downmixes to 2 channels